# Error creating APK Build with React Native having EXPO

Tags: android, react-native, build, expo

I'm trying to use to build an Android APK in my React Native app having expo installed. I've tried in many ways... and always had the same problem telling that some package from Android doesn't exist. This is only a example because the error is replicated with many Android packages.

```
> Task :expo-modules-core:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
[stderr] /home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/core/ViewManager.java:3: 
error: package android.content does not exist
[stderr] import android.content.Context;
```

I think this error could be related with **versions** or versions configuration. I don't know if it could be Java SKD, Expo or something like that.
If anyone could help me please!!

[image]

```
openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu11.56+19-CA (build 11.0.15+10-LTS, mixed mode)
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "AppNative",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook",
    "format:all": "eslint . --fix && prettier . --write",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.10",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.6.2",
    "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^6.4.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.67.3",
    "expo": "^45.0.6",
    "expo-dev-client": "~1.0.0",
    "expo-device": "~4.2.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.15.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.13.4",
    "native-base": "^3.4.7",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.13.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.22.4",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.0",
    "@babel/helper-builder-react-jsx-experimental": "^7.12.11",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.4.20",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.20",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^6.4.20",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.4.20",
    "@storybook/addon-react-native-web": "^0.0.18",
    "@storybook/react": "^6.4.20",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.9",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.43",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.30.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.17.7",
    "eslint": "^8.18.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^17.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-n": "^15.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.30.1",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-storybook": "^0.5.7",
    "husky": ">=7",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "lint-staged": ">=10",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.17.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,css,scss,md}": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix"
    ]
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of searching... I finally found a solution in this github issue.
https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17862

As [@Kudo](https://github.com/Kudo) says to solve the issue I was using another gradle build version. So I had to change it in my build.gradle file. Make sure is **7.0.4**

**android/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4')
}
```